# How do I Delete Related entites in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am trying to Delete related entities with main entity in EF6

GroupageJob and GroupageAddresses are having fk relationship with one groupagejob with many groupageaddresses
Here is code I wrote

```
     var gaddrs= groupagejob.GroupageAddresses.Where(i=>i.TransportJobId==2);
               foreach (var gaddr in gaddrs)
               {
                  // db.GroupageAddresses.Remove(gaddr);
                   db.Entry(gaddr).State = EntityState.Deleted;
               }
         groupagejob.Status = TransportJobStatus.Delivered.ToString();           
         db.Entry(groupagejob).State = EntityState.Modified;
         var effroes = db.SaveChanges();
```

I am getting error that ,
adding a relationship with an entity which is in the deleted state is not allowed

Comment: Can you expalin the relation ship between the two and what are you trying to achive here ?

Comment: GroupageJob and GroupageAddresses are having fk relationship with one groupagejob with many groupageaddresses

Comment: SO some more code: where do you create the context instance? Why don't you use directly the `Delete`method for the details, and let change tracking detect the modificacion of the main entity? You're doing it the hard way

Comment: I have context in basecontroller(mvc)and used common inherited controller in all the derived controllers

Comment: @JotaBe can u let me know how to write above code in your way